# Specific initial date/time when loading DatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I'm using a DatePicker for my program, and was curious if I could set a specific initial date/time to show when DatePicker is opened. I was wondering if I could set the initial date to the current year, month a date. But for the time section, start at 8 AM.

```
startTimeDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[startTimeDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
startTimeTextField.text = [startTimeDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I need the time to show up as (for example: 2014-06-12 08:00:00).

Thank you

Comment: Can you include the DatePicker declaration from your ViewController?

Comment: @VineetBhatia Why? The question is about creating an `NSDate` with a specific time.

Comment: Don't need to. Problem solved. See Stonz' answer.

Comment: Your question title seemed to indicate issue with initializing UIDatePicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[comps setHour:8];
[comps setMinute:0];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSDate *dateFromComps = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps]; // current date/month/year set to 8:00am

startTimeDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[startTimeDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
startTimeTextField.text = [startTimeDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromComps];

datePicker.date = dateFromComps;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use the `setDate:` method on your picker view.

```
[_datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: The question is how to set it to a specific time, not the current date/time.